# Wireshark remote monitoring error: no remote interfaces found

Tags: networking, router, wireshark

I am using `wireshark` for monitoring my home router traffic I have installed `winpcap` and I also started **Remote Packet Capture Protocol service**

when I try to add remote interface and I am adding my own router IP (and port number 2002) I get this message:

> no remote interfaces found.

Can anybody tell me what should I do now??
 Please help me or give me an Alternative way

PS:
1. I tried both options authentication and null authentication but the results was the same 

2. I followed this link method step by step [part:Capturing Traffic From Remote Computers](https://www.howtogeek.com/106191/5-killer-tricks-to-get-the-most-out-of-wireshark/)

Comment: Wait.. just to clarify, you are trying to monitor your "home router" traffic? Is your home router a PC/Windows based device? (and if it is) have you installed WinPCap on THAT device? If your router is a normal router - it is certainly is not running Windows, and most likely you have not installed WinPCAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That how to guide is misleading. You can't do a remote packet capture with Wireshark on a router unless it is a Windows based router running the winpcap software.

Your home router is a piece of hardware. It isn't running the necessary software to work with Wireshark.

Notice it says to install WinPCap on the "remote" machine.

This is not easily possible on a home network. Alternative methods deserve their own thread and all require advanced networking knowledge and dedicated hardware and / or software.